# How Can I Remove Specific HTML Tables?

Tags: c#, html, html-table, dreamweaver

I want to retrieve every table in the document that contains only one row and one cell.  Those tables should then be entirely replaced with the contents of that single cell.  For example, the below table should replaced with its text:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Sample Text
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

converted to:
Sample Text

Can any of html editors such as MS Expression Web or DreamWeaver help for this or do I have to write a program?
I have some experience in C#.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want to programatically retrieve data from HTML?

Comment: Only remove tables that contain a row and column?  Do you mean 'only have one of each' or just has them in general.  If the latter, wouldn't that be every table or do you have empty tables?  Why do you have empty tables?!

Comment: If one application can do it it is better otherwise i have to wrtite a simple program but i need help for that because i'm a begginer also i mean tables that conation exacltly one row and one column

Answer (score 1):

This will find every table with 1 row and 1 cell and replace it with its inner text.

```
var allTables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
for(a=0; a<allTables.length; a++){
var allRows = allTables[a].getElementsByTagName("tr");
var allCells = allRows[0].getElementsByTagName("td");
  if(allRows.length===1 && allCells.length===1){
    var tdInnards = document.createElement("div");
        tdInnards.appendChild(document.createTextNode(allCells[0].innerHTML));
    }
  }
  allTables[a].insertBefore(tdInnards);
  allTables[a].parentNode.removeChild(allTables[a]);
}
```

However, this is only JavaScript so it will aesthetically accomplish what you want, but won't actually rewrite the page.  You could perhaps use something similar to parse the text and output the result.

Comment: Every tables have some rows and some columns but because of some reasons i have some tables that conation only one row and one column so i don't need theme and i want to replace theme with plane text thank you

Comment: If this is for performance of loading the page only (so it doesn't need to render a table, just text) javascript is going to make it worse. The browser will have already loaded the table and needs to change that part once the javascript kicks in. I'd say don't waste your time...

Comment: @Peter: You're absolutely right, when I write the answer, what he was trying to do wasn't completely clear.  I left it because I plan on improving the answer when I get a chance.

Comment: @Fantabulum: I figured as much. Good answer! My comment was directed towards the OP as his request is a little vague as to why he wants to do this.

Comment: i've wrote the code in c# and it works very nice anyway thanks evryone